# Is there a formula to calculate the amount of gold that a top ten pirate will give you?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

In Pirates! is there a formula to calculate the amount of gold that a top ten pirate will give you?

The more time that a pirate stays plundering they give more money. Is it a time ratio?

Comment: I can't confirm this at the moment, but I believe that you'll get 10% of the value that you see them listed at on the top 10 page.

Answer (score 3):

I recently played this on the iPad and while I wasn't trying to do exact math, I seem to remember thinking I was getting about 1/10th of their listed value on the Top 10 page when I defeated them.

[This FAQ seems to back the idea that you'll receive 10% of their listed value.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/915017-sid-meiers-pirates/faqs/34143)

> It is possible to predict how much gold capturing a pirate will get you. Just
>   have a look at the Top 10 Pirates list, and have a look at how much gold
>   they've plundered over their career. Exactly 10% of that will be on board
>   their ship when you capture it. Pirate wealth (as well as their other stats)
>   updates at the beginning of every month, so decide for yourself if you want
>   to capture them early, or leave them be for a while so you can go after them
>   later in your career and get more gold.

Comment: that confirms my memories of the game as well