# Raiders and their Gold

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

In Sid Meier's Pirates the Top ten Pirates will roam about the Caribbean slowly gaining wealth. Based on when you take them you gain more gold.

This got me thinking about raiders and how they can slowly accumulate gold from captured prizes.

Is it possible to wait at the last minute for a raider to stop raiding ships to earn more gold from them. Or do the ships always have a set amount when leaving their ports?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a formula to calculate the amount of gold that a top ten pirate will give you?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149041/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-amount-of-gold-that-a-top-ten-pirate-will-gi)

Comment: @spartacus No actually not. There is a listed amount of gold that a top ten pirate has.

Comment: I think this question is more about how/when a top ten pirate gains value, not how much you get for taking them.

Comment: @Kexlox This isn't even about the Top Ten I only added them as a reference.

Comment: Well then, you may need to edit your question to clarify your intent.  It would seem that neither spartacus nor I understand what you are asking.  Judging by the close votes, neither does anyone else.